# Calculate mean across 2 variables of a 3 variable data.frame

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame with color, quality and price and I want to compare how the color changes perception of quality.
I need to get a table with the mean of the prices for every color and quality combination.
I am currently trying with aggregate but I can't seem to find the proper combination.

`aggregate(price ~ color, list(Quality = D$quality), data=D, FUN=mean);`

Input:
`Quality   | Color | Price
Good      | Red   | 4500
Excellent | Green | 5000
Bad       | Blue  | 420
......`

Output: mean prices table
`.         Red .    Blue . Green
Excellent . 4520 .  4200 .  3500 
Good .      3950 .  3722 .  3021
Bad .       1523 .  1232 .  900`

Comment: make a reproducible example with simulated data or dput and desired output

Comment: Look here: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: try: `aggregate(price ~ color + quality, data=D, FUN=mean)`

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>% 
  summarise(M_mpg=mean(mpg)) %>% 
  spread(cyl, M_mpg)
```